# How to use angular ng-repeat with an Web api?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, webapi

I'm trying to build a website using front-end html and get its data from a Web-api. My Web-api returns a json format. So I was trying to use the Get request using Angular $http and ng-repeat directive. My angular controller is like this -

```
'use strict';  app.controller('blogsController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('www.example.com/api/blog')
   .then(function(res){
      $scope.blogs = res.data;
    });
}]);
```

The html code looks like this -

```
<body app="ng-app" >
   <div ng-repeat="xr in blogs" >
     <div id="blog_title" >
       {{xr.blog_title}}
     </div>

     <div id="blog_text">
       {{xr.blog_text}}
     </div>
   </div>

</body>
```

I have tried this but this is not getting me the data from the blog web api.

Please help me to get the solution.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is nothing wrong in your code

```
<div ng-repeat="xr in blogs" >
     <div id="blog_title" >
       {{xr.blog_title}}
     </div>

     <div id="blog_text">
       {{xr.blog_text}}
     </div>
   </div>
```

but make sure that your `res.data` must follow an arrangement like below:

```
res.data = [{'blog_title': 'title value1', 'blog_text':'text value'}
            {'blog_title': 'title value2', 'blog_text':'text value'}
            {'blog_title': 'title value3', 'blog_text':'text value'}]
```

print your `res.data` in web console using `console.log` to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ng-controller on the template, and **`app`** should be **`ng-app`**

```
<body ng-app="ng-app" ng-controller="blogsController">
   <div ng-repeat="xr in blogs" >
     <div id="blog_title" >
       {{xr.blog_title}}
     </div>

     <div id="blog_text">
       {{xr.blog_text}}
     </div>
   </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I have added ng-controller but still it's not working.